# jquery mouseleave event after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, mouseleave

I have script, when i am showing div after click event, and after this div is shown, i need hide the same element on mouseleave event. I am trying this script...

```
 $(function () {
    $('#facts-header-navigation .cat').on('click', function () {
        $('#facts-header-categories .header-categories').show(400);
    }, function () {
        $('#facts-header-categories').on('mouseleave', function () {
            $('#facts-header-categories .header-categories').hide(400);
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you for every advice how to solve this problem.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the page HTML and details on what is happening with your current script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in first , check your script link

```
        $('#facts-header-navigation .cat').on('click', function () {
            $('#facts-header-categories .header-categories').show(400);
        });
        $('#facts-header-categories').on('mouseleave', function () {
                $('#facts-header-categories .header-categories').hide(400);
        });
```

**Or**

```
        $(document).on('click','#facts-header-navigation .cat', function () {
            $('#facts-header-categories .header-categories').show(400);
        });
         $(document).on('mouseleave','#facts-header-navigation .cat', function () {
                $('#facts-header-categories .header-categories').hide(400);
        });
```